# how to auto generate id from date in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to auto generate Id from date entered by user.
 Example: date is 12/05/2017 than id must 170001 or 5/10/2014 than id must 140001

```html
     private void autogeneratedocno()
       {
        con.Open();
        string check="select count(Doc_no) from       
        complaint";
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(check,con);
        int a =Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());

        string date = txtdate.Text.ToString();
        string year = date.Substring(8, 2);
        //string[] arrDate = date.Split('/');

        //string day = arrDate[0].ToString();
        //string month = arrDate[1].ToString();
        //string year = arrDate[2].ToString();
        //string y = year.Substring(2, 2);

        if (a == 0)
        {
         
            txtdocno.Text = string.Concat( year.ToString()
            + "00000");

        }
        else
        {
            string count = "select ISNULL(MAX(Doc_no),0)+1
            from complaint";                             
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(count, con);
            int doc_no =
            Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            txtdocno.Text = doc_no.ToString();
      
        }
        con.Close();
        }
```

by using above code. i am able to generate id for year 2017 but when i change the year the first two digits are not changing.

please suggest me changes to autogenerate ID

Comment: Welcome to SO, This question is way too broad, Please take a minute to read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and maybe [Writing the perfect question,](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and try writing a better question, detailing more requirements, showing us what you have tried already and where you are stuck. Good luck!

Comment: Can you please add some more details. Why must 12/05/2017 = 170001, what if two people enter the same date, should the Id always be the same?

Comment: no, id is always  auto incremented.

Comment: the id is depend on entered year if it is 2017 than the first two nubers would be 17 if it is 2015 than the starting two numbers would be 15

Comment: and if the year is same than the id must be incremented eg: 1700001,1700002,1700003.........

Comment: There are still many unknowns in this question. Where are you saving the Ids, What if the year is 2009 = would your id be 090001 making the Id a string not an int, what happens when you get to 1799999, would the increment got to 1800000 and so on... I would also advise you edit the question rather than adding comments. Can you give more detail what exactly you need help with, stripping the year from the date, increment a number? And do you have any code that would show us what you have attempted so far.

Comment: Id from input is *not a smart move* it won't be unique anymore

Comment: i am using this autogenerated Id for complaints so 99999 complaints are more enough for one year in my project  @Scrobi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
    private void autogeneratedocno()
    {


        string str1 = txtdate.Text;
        string[] s1 = str1.Split('/');
        str1 = s1[1].ToString() + "/" + s1[0].ToString() +
        "/" + s1[2].ToString();

        string yy = s1[2].ToString();
        string mm = s1[1].ToString();
        string dd = s1[0].ToString();

        int y = Convert.ToInt32(yy);
        int m = Convert.ToInt32(mm);

        string z = yy.Substring(2,2);

        string sqlno =" selectisnull(max(substring
        (doc_no,3,5)),0)+1 from complaint where
        substring(doc_no,1,2) = '"+z+"'";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlno, con);
        string getno =
        Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();
        string Inquiry_code = yy.Substring(2, 2) +
        getno.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
        txtdocno.Text = Inquiry_code;

    }
```

finally got the answer.

Please Suggest if you have other Ideas to do this.

Comment: I would suggest using the correct data type for the data. So use a DateTime for dates. 
But the code above should do what you want it todo. You may want to look at what will happen when a user enters a date in a format you are not expecting or a string that is not a date at all.

Comment: thanx for your suggestions @Scrobi. i will remember that .... also i am having another issue please help in my next question

Answer (score 0):

lbldate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

```
    string Year = lbldate.Text.Substring(8, 2);
    lblYear.Text = Year;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you solve the problem you are having, but you may find you will have other issues down the line.

I opted to converting the string input to a DateTime as you cannot guarantee what a user will input. What if they enter the date like 2017-01-01.

For instance this will fail for 2009 as the int.parse will remove the leading zeros.

```
string date = "01/01/2017"; //example date
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(date); //convert string into datetime
var i = int.Parse(d.ToString("yy00000")); //format and convert to int

int docno = i + count
```

You should maybe look at generating a number from the database or possibly using a GUID